# Save And Load A Single Value, iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, load, save, uilabel

I have a feeling there is a simple way to do this. I have a number between 1 and 100 and it is stored in a variable called firstValue. This variable is then put into a UILabel. When the user exits my app, I want this firstValue to be saved so that when the app is loaded by the user this number can be re-inserted into the UILabel (firstValueLabel.text).

Many thanks,

Stuart

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use NSUserDefaults for this.

To save it:

```
NSInteger myValue = ...; // This is your number
NSString *key = ... ; // This is a string to identify your number
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:myValue forKey:key];
```

To read it:

```
NSInteger myValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:key];
```

If no previous value has been saved, the value returned will be 0.

Add this to your applicationWillTerminate:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: It is better to call the `synchronize` method after you have changed the value. Just in case your app crashes or stops for some other reason.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the NSUserDefaults to store some variable for your application to retrieve them after a close of the application.
For exemple:

```
// Set the name of the view
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:10 forKey:@"firstValue"];
```

To retrieve the last action of the user:

```
// Retrieve the last view name
Integer firstValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"firstValue"];
```

But you can add other than a integer. (see the [NSUserDefaults Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html))